# sortable row with same group in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have one table and i want to group first 3rd row and then group other rows, and when i try to move rows then it'll work for only those group.

Here is the jsfiddle which i try : [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/n57fu/26/).

```js
// Sortable rows
 $('.sorted_table').sortable({
  containerSelector: 'table',
  itemPath: '> tbody',
  itemSelector: 'tr.x',
  placeholder: '<tr class="placeholder"/>'
}); 

$('.sorted_table').sortable({
  containerSelector: 'table',
  itemPath: '> tbody',
  itemSelector: 'tr.y',
  placeholder: '<tr class="placeholder"/>'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sortable/0.9.13/jquery-sortable.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered sorted_table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>A Column</th>
                    <th>B Column</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="x">
                    <td>A Item 2</td>
                    <td>B Item 2</td>
                  </tr><tr class="x">
                    <td>A Item 5</td>
                    <td>B Item 5</td>
                  </tr><tr class="x">
                    <td>A Item 4</td>
                    <td>B Item 4</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="y">
                    <td>A Item 6</td>
                    <td>B Item 6</td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  
                  
                  <tr class="y">
                    <td>A Item 3</td>
                    <td>B Item 3</td>
                  </tr><tr class="y">
                    <td>A Item 1</td>
                    <td>B Item 1</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

I want something like this . class x rows can move within class x and class y rows move withing class y rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered sorted_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A Column</th>
      <th>B Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="x">
    <tr>
      <td>A Item 2</td>
      <td>B Item 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A Item 5</td>
      <td>B Item 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A Item 4</td>
      <td>B Item 4</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

  <tbody class="y">
   <tr>
      <td>A Item 6</td>
      <td>B Item 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A Item 3</td>
      <td>B Item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A Item 1</td>
      <td>B Item 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
// Sortable rows with class x
$('.sorted_table').find('.x').sortable();

// Sortable rows with class y
$('.sorted_table').find('.y').sortable();
```

[**Online Demo (jsFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/u6Lzpm0s/24/)